# haskell: maximum product consecutive digits in a number

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that finds the highest product of `k` consecutive digits of a given `z` number with  `n` digits.

For example:

```
z = 1240313 -- number entered
n = 7 -- number of digits

k = 2 => 2*4 => 8 -- example if k = 2
k = 3 => 3*1*3 => 9
k = 4 => 0
```

If `k > n` I'm suppoused to get back an error.

My idea until now is to get all the digits one by one from the given number `z` and insert them on a list. Then I could probably work with this list but I don't know exactly how.

I managed to handle the error (I think) 
here is my code until now:

```
myList 0 = []
myList x = (x `mod` 10 : myList (x `div` 10))

myReverse x = reverse (myList x)

maxConProduct :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
maxConProduct z k | k > length(myReverse) = error "more consecutive digits entered as required"
```

I'm new in Haskell and in the programming world. I would appreciate any help I can get on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR:

```
maximum . map product . takeWhile ((==n).length) . map (take n) . tails
```

### Compose functions

You can do this very cleanly by composing functions:

```
import Data.List (tails)
import Data.Char (isDigit)

maxProd :: (Num a, Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> a
maxProd n = maximum                      -- biggest
          . map product                  -- product in the list
          . takeWhile ((== n) . length)  -- once the too-short ones have gone
          . map (take n)                 -- when you take the first n of each
          . tails                        -- of the tails of the original
```

Note that

```
((== n) . length) :: [a] -> Bool
```

first finds the length of the list, then gives `True` if that length matches `n`.

### How does it work?

By way of illustration, let's track that through on your example. Notice how the tails have all lengths, but then when we `map (take 3)` it just keeps the first three of each. Also notice there are three lists that are too short (`[1,3],[3],[]`), so that's why we `takeWhile ((==3).length)`.

```
ghci> tails $ [1,2,4,0,3,1,3]
[[1,2,4,0,3,1,3],[2,4,0,3,1,3],[4,0,3,1,3],[0,3,1,3],[3,1,3],[1,3],[3],[]]
ghci> map (take 3) . tails $ [1,2,4,0,3,1,3] 
[[1,2,4],[2,4,0],[4,0,3],[0,3,1],[3,1,3],[1,3],[3],[]]
ghci> takeWhile ((==3).length) . map (take 3) . tails $ [1,2,4,0,3,1,3]
[[1,2,4],[2,4,0],[4,0,3],[0,3,1],[3,1,3]]
ghci> map product . takeWhile ((==3).length) . map (take 3) . tails $ [1,2,4,0,3,1,3]
[8,0,0,0,9]
ghci> maximum . map product . takeWhile ((==3).length) . map (take 3) . tails $ [1,2,4,0,3,1,3]
9
```

### Making it less unhelpful

Now this gives an error when `n` is more than the original list's length because the `takeWhile` will filter out all of the lists, and you'll be taking the maximum of an empty list, but it'll be more helpful with a clearer message. It's also handy to convert from a single Int:

```
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits = map (read . (:"")) . show
```

That works by turning each character of the shown String into a String itself by putting it in front of the empty String with (:""), then reading each. Originally I had it taking from a String, because I erroneously thought that's what you had. Never mind.

```
findMaxProd :: Int -> Int -> Int
findMaxProd n i
          | n > length (show i) = error "findMaxProd: product length exceeds number length"
          | otherwise = maxProd n . digits $ i
```

In action, that gives:

```
ghci> findMaxProd 10 1240313
*** Exception: findMaxProd: product length exceeds number length
ghci> findMaxProd 3 1240313
9
```

Comment: [or](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24609264/849891) `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) . take n . tails` etc. But your way is more didactic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be like this:

```
maxConProduct z k | k > length (myReverse z) = error "more consecutive digits entered as required"
maxConProduct z k = solve (myReverse z) [] k
  where solve :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Int -> a
        solve [] acc _ = head $ reverse $ sort acc
        solve x'@(x:xs) acc k = if k > length x'
                                then solve [] acc k
                                else solve xs (product (take k x'):acc) k
```

Demo in ghci:

```
λ> maxConProduct 1240313 2
8
λ> maxConProduct 1240313 3
9
λ> maxConProduct 1240313 4
0
λ> maxConProduct 1240313 8
*** Exception: more consecutive digits entered as required
```

You can see in the `solve` function, that I'm taking product of all the first `k` numbers and accumulating them in the list `acc`. Once the input list is empty, then I just sort the `acc` and give out the highest element in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
maxProduct number k 
  | length (show number) < k = error "more consecutive digits entered as required"
  | otherwise = maxProductHelp (transform number) k
    where
      transform 0 = []
      transform number = mod number 10 : transform (div number 10) -- returns digits
      maxProductHelp digits k = maximum $ products digits k -- gets maximum
        where
          products d k -- returns a list of products of consecutive groups of length k 
            | length d < k = []
            | otherwise = (product $ take k d) : products (tail d) k
```

Your `maxConProduct` is implemented as `maximum $ products digits k`

Lets look at this solution:

- `maxProduct` calls `maxProductHelp`, with the number somehow changed.
- `transform` just returns the digits of the specified number.
- `maxProductHelp` now gets the maximum of a list that `products` returned.
- `products` returns a list of the product of consecutive sublists of length `k`.

The most important function is `products` which is relatively easy to understand:

Well we want products to return a list of products of `k` consecutive digits, so we just cons the product of `k` consecutive digits into the next product of `k` consecutive digits. If our list of remaining digits is shorter than our specified `k` then we return an empty list on which everything is consed back.

Here just a small example of `products`:

```
products [3,1,3,0,4,2,1] 3 = (product [3,1,3]) : products [1,3,0,4,2,1]
products [1,3,0,2,4,2,1] 3 = (product [1,3,0]) : products [3,0,4,2,1]
products [3,0,4,2,1] 3 = (product [3,0,4]) : products [0,4,2,1]
products [0,4,2,1] 3 = (product [0,4,2]]) : products [4,2,1]
products [4,2,1] 3 = (product [4,2,1]]) : products [2,1]
products [2,1] = []
```

This is all just a list:

```
9 : 0 : 0 : 0 : 8 : [] == [9,0,0,0,8]
```